# Deleting dynamically allocated objects with private destructors

Tags: c++, destructor, dynamic-memory-allocation

So I came across a code snippet which demonstrated that *if we want forced dynamic allocation of any class object, we should make its destructor private*.

I tried that and yes it doesn't allow one to instantiate object on stack. But when I instantiated a dynamically allocated instance and tried deleting the object (or it would cause leak) - I kept on getting warning about destructor being private.

How can I properly manage memory of a dynamically allocated object which has a private destructor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like accessing any other private member function, you must do it in a member or a friend function. An example:

```
class foo {
    ~foo(){}
public:
    static void del(const foo* ptr)
    {
        delete ptr;
    }
};
```

Or even better, force the client to use smart pointer:

```
class foo {
    ~foo(){}
    struct deleter {
        void operator()(const foo* ptr)
        {
            delete ptr;
        }
    };
public:
    static std::unique_ptr<foo, deleter> make(/*args*/)
    {
        return {new foo(/*args*/), {}};
    }
};
```

Comment: hello @eerorika: thanks for quick answer. It works. I tried it. May I know any particular reason you have chosen to make the method static?

Comment: @User9102d82 Although it is well defined to `delete this`, not everybody know that and being unusual it tends to raise confusion.

Comment: @Quentin It doesn't need to be. `foo::deleter` is a member of `foo`, so it has access to all of `foo`'s private members.

Comment: @Brian [it has indeed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nested_types), since C++11. I'm baffled to never have encountered that property before...

Answer (score 3):

Providing a deleting function works as far as access control goes, but forces the users of your class to use custom deleters everywhere. It is more concise all around to just befriend the standard default deleter:

```
struct Foo {
private:
    friend std::default_delete<Foo>;
    ~Foo() = default;
};

auto p = std::make_unique<Foo>(); // Works out of the box
```

Comment: Nice. Simpler than my idea.

Comment: Note that this is not strictly conforming, since `std::default_delete` is allowed to, say, call some internal free function that contains the actual `delete` call (at which point the destructor would be inaccessible).

Comment: @Brian fair enough, that looks like a standard oversight though. A specialization of `std::default_delete<Foo>` would work around such a quirk.

Comment: Good point. I did try to delete the object just like you described and it leak still happened. But then how is the pointer actually deleted? Where can I read about that.

Comment: @User9102d82 I'm sorry, but I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

The only good reason to force an object to be dynamically allocated is that it needs to manage its own lifetime somehow. Otherwise, the code that creates the object is responsible for managing its lifetime---and as automatic storage duration is a valid lifetime management strategy, it ought not to be disabled intentionally.

So, I will suppose that your object manages its own lifetime; for example, perhaps it maintains a reference count, then calls `delete this` in the `release()` method when the reference count goes to 0. Then the answer to the question of "how to properly manage the object's lifetime", as a *user* of the object, is "use the object properly", so that the object will deallocate itself when the time is right.

For example, a `std::unique_ptr` with a custom deleter can be used to ensure that the object's `release()` is called on scope exit, preventing any references from being leaked.

Comment: you are right about the "good reason" part. I am studying about ACE Reactor framework, and it suggests to only dynamically allocate the objects (owing it to the internal working of the Reactor), hence I came across this issue for the first time.

Comment: +1 for your inputs and explanation. It was helpful to understand more things about the situation. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one example:

```
class Example {
public:
    void kill_me() { // a public function
        delete this; // is allowed to delete
    }
private:
    ~Example() {}    // private destructor
};

int main() {
    Example* e = new Example;
    e->kill_me();
}
```